# Phpmyadmin vs Jetbrains Datagrip for database management

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-management, datagrip

I have been working with `Phpmyadmin` for quite some time and recently i came across `Jetbrains` `Phpstorm` and `Intellij` which i both really liked.

Now i found the database environment `Datagrip`.

I wanted to know objectively:

- what are the advantages of `Datagrip` over `Phpmyadmin` and vice versa.
- What does `Datagrip`give me that `Phpmyadmin` lacks?
- What does `Phpmyadmin` give me that `Datagrip` lacks?

Comment: I can tell you that DataGrip provides fast code completion, based on the syntax — it can even complete your JOIN clause based on foreign keys. It also has data editor — so you can edit several cells at once or you can edit many rows locally and then submit them.

Comment: Also you can navigate inside the grid by foreign keys. What else? Multi-cursor in the editor  can help you edit a bunch of statements. And renaming the table in script will rename it in database as well. From 2016.3 version there will be 'find usages" feature which will help you to know in what views, procs, triggers the needed table is used.

Comment: @moscas i you could write an answer i would be happy to except it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using PhpStorm and Datagrip since February 2017. Before that I was using Dreamweaver and PhpMyAdmin.

The only thing PhpMyAdmin had an advantage over Datagrip from my perspective, was searching the whole database. But since 2019 Datagrip has a "full text search" which does exactly the same.

Furthermore:

- Datagrip is fully integrated into your IDE (PhpStorm, PyCharme, IntelliJ, etc). You don't need to leave it to run any SQL queries.
- within the SQL console you have access to the "live templates" which let you insert huge code snippets impossible to remember via typing a few letters of the live template name. Before:
  [image]
  after:
  [image]
- SQL consoles are saved automatically (by a consecutive number). And you can save them as SQL files to any directory right from the console via ctrl/cmd + s
- you also have access to the IDE's huge clipboard with (in my case) 100 previously copied text pieces, while each of them can be a whole (SQL) document:
  [image]
- it so easy to modify a table without writing any queries (table name, column name, foreign keys, indexes, column data type, etc):

[image]
[image]

- the tables and search results are super easy to edit and update as if you would edit an Excel table
- you can assign to /setup on any project as many databases as you like and  access them easily
- you can assign/setup and access any remote database via an SSH tunnel
- you can assign/setup any type of DBMS:

[image]

- Datagrip checks the SQL query syntax live, before you even run it
- this is my IDE setup for testing query time on two identical sites running on different server setups (the one on nginx/mysql and the other one on Openlitespeed/Mariadb):

[image]

All that you get only for a couple of bucks! I pay now for PhpStorm only 80€ annually! I pay often much more for a single site license of some shitty wordpress plugin! But get a really really high quality software product with PhpStorm. Seriously, probably the only company I would LOVE to work as employee (being freelancer throughout my whole dev "career") is probably JetBrains. It seems as they can read my thoughts :D. Sure there are some few minor issues. But any time they bring out a new version I am excited as a child.

No I'm not paid by JetBrains :D And no I don't hype them because I'm Russian. At the time I felt in love with them I thought it is a Czech company with a bunch of Russian devs (nothing unusual in Europe). And Czech's in general don't like Russians. So I loved them even I thought they wouldn't love me :D Only a year after I've switched from Dreamweaver to PhpStorm I've found out it is a fully Russian company.

The only thing I hate in Datagrip is that the SQL console output shares for any reason a tab/window with Docker (dafuq?) and it is a huge pain in the as* to navigate between multiple query outputs/results (as in the example above where I compare the performance of two servers)

Update: 
the only flaw of Datagrip from my perspective (pain in the as* to switch between console outputs) has gone now as well! :D 
I've found a setting by which you can just simply open a "services" tree (Command + Shift + T) which list all the active/latest "services". I still don't understand why the Datagrip console output doesn't have a dedicated window, but at least I can now navigate easily between the different console's output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What does Datagripgive me that Phpmyadmin lacks?

DataGrip provides fast code completion, based on the syntax — it can even complete your JOIN clause based on foreign keys.

It also has data editor — so you can edit several cells at once or you can edit many rows locally and then submit them.

Also you can navigate inside the grid y foreign keys.

Multi-cursor in the editor can help you edit a bunch of statements.

> What does Phpmyadmin give me that Datagrip lacks?

PhpMyAdmin can export to PDF, ISO/IEC 26300 - OpenDocument Text and Spreadsheet, Word, LATEX

PhpMyAdmin has more administration features, dataGrip is not focused at administration at all

It also supports working with user accounts and privileges